# Laraval array validation with unique email while update

Tags: laravel, validation

Updating form but email should be unique, `request('contacts.*.id')` is empty. It should have ID of that row. How can i get that ID?

```
        return [
        'email' => "required|email|unique:clients,email,".request('id'),
        'client_type_text' => 'required',
        'client_name' => 'required',
        'phone_number' => 'required',
        'contacts' => 'required|array',
        'contacts.*.firstname' => 'required',
        'contacts.*.lastname' => 'required',
        'contacts.*.mobile' => 'required',
        'contacts.*.email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.request('contacts.*.id'),
    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work

```
return [
            'email' => "required|email|unique:clients,email,".request('id'),
            'client_type_text' => 'required',
            'client_name' => 'required',
            'phone_number' => 'required',
            'contacts' => 'required|array',
            'contacts.*.firstname' => 'required',
            'contacts.*.lastname' => 'required',
            'contacts.*.mobile' => 'required',
            // check if email is unique for each contact id
            'contacts.*.email' => [
                'required',
                'email',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    $contact_id = explode('.', $attribute)[1];
                    $client_id = request('id');
                    $contact = \App\Models\Contact::where('id', $contact_id)->where('client_id', $client_id)->first();
                    if ($contact) {
                        $contact_email = $contact->email;
                        if ($contact_email != $value) {
                            $contact_with_email = \App\Models\Contact::where('email', $value)->first();
                            if ($contact_with_email) {
                                $fail('The email has already been taken.');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            ],
        ];
```

Comment: I modified this to use in my case.
`'contacts.*.email' => ['required','email',function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {$user_id = explode('.', $attribute)[1];$contact = User::where('id', request(sprintf("contacts.%s.id", $user_id)))->first();if ($contact) {$contact_email = $contact->email;if ($contact_email != $value) { $contact_with_email = User::where('email', $value)->first(); if ($contact_with_email) {$fail('The email has already been taken.'); }} } },],`